# What does a phony docker.* target mean in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

What is the meaning of this `make` target:

```
.PHONY: docker.%
docker.%:
    go mod tidy
    docker build -t $* .
    docker run -p 5751:5751 -v $$(pwd)/:/work $* /work/config.yaml
```

In particular, what is the meaning of `%` in `docker.%` and how is it being utilized here?

Comment: `.PHONY` and `%` wildcard are explained in the [GNU Make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions). In short, `.PHONY` means that `docker.%` is a target but is not represented by a file in your current directory that has to be built. And `%` is a wildcard. the `$*` value in the commands will have the value of whatever `%` is when you call `make` on the target, *e.g.*, `make docker.foo`.

Comment: ... so the net effect in the given makefile is similar to declaring a one-argument function named "docker".  You call it with argument `foo` by running `make docker.foo`.